# Run Docker container as daemon without login

Tags: windows, docker, daemon

I have created a GitLab container in Docker on the Windows 10 operating system. I used Docker Desktop for this purpose. I would like to run the container as a kind of daemon so that the container starts when the system boots regardless of a login.

Various options like `--detach` and `--restart always` specified when running the container. They do not lead to the desired result.

How would you create a Docker container as a daemon or service on Windows?

Additionally, I tried registering dockerd with the command `dockerd --register-service`. However, dockerd does not tell me much. Does anyone have sample code on how to use it to deploy a container as a daemon?

Edit

I observed again what happens when i set the `--restart always` option:

when I enter services.msc in the command line after reboot, the entry Docker Desktop Service is listed there.
[image]

However, my container is not accessible and the `docker ps` command in Powershell also shows an error:

```
error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
```

But when I start Docker from the desktop icon, everything works fine.

Comment: `--restart always` should work, as long as the docker service is running on start up. There is also the service manager in windows control panel. Is the docker service running there after reboot?

Comment: @Alex Thank you for your reply. I have checked again the solution with the --restart always option. Please look again at my edit.

Comment: hm, then I have no clue, sorry